# Add cells to uitableView Like Mail.app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to add cells into UItableView like in mail.app on ipad. In my cells I have UITextFields, and I have change this method to set focus

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
    NSLog(@"%d",newIndexPath.row);
   UITextField* field =  (UITextField *) [tblView viewWithTag: newIndexPath.row];

    int l_cellNum = field.tag;
    if(l_cellNum == 1 && isAddedNewRow == FALSE){
        isAddedNewRow = TRUE;
        [cellsArray insertObject:@"CC" atIndex:1];
        [cellsArray insertObject:@"BCC" atIndex:2];

        CGRect tvbounds = [tblView bounds];
        [tblView setBounds:CGRectMake(tvbounds.origin.x, 
                                      tvbounds.origin.y, 
                                      tvbounds.size.width, 
                                      tvbounds.size.height)];
        NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        NSIndexPath *path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
        NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1,path2,nil];
       [tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [field becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

But when I click to one of the cell i add 2 cells (like mail.app) but my tags for textFields do not updates, and I cant to set focus on it =(. If I call reloaddata method it calls -cellForRowAtIndexPath with this new cells at the beggining and after for all cells, and it will not work too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a built-in style of cells called `UITableViewStyleSubtitle`, where you can customize the subtitle just like the iPad Mail.app. Take a look at this page in the [iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1). Then, you can set the subtitle of the `UITableViewCell` to the text that you need.
Additionally, the iOS doc has more information about [customizing table view cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).